# How to pull from docker hub - pull access denied repository does not exist or may require 'docker login'

Tags: docker, dockerhub, docker-pull

I have pulled images from Docker before - some time ago - but now it seems things have changed.

Take for example https://hub.docker.com/r/datagrip. Documentation states installation as follows

```
docker pull sath89/oracle-xe-11g
```

This no longer works with current Docker hub. I can try latest

```
[myuser:~] $ docker pull sath89/oracle-xe-11g
Using default tag: latest
Error response from daemon: pull access denied for sath89/oracle-xe-11g, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login'
```

Or tag `11.2`

```
[myuser:~] 1 $ docker pull sath89/oracle-xe-11g:11.2
Error response from daemon: pull access denied for sath89/oracle-xe-11g, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login'
```

Of course I can try login - login succeeds but pulling images is still not working.

```
[myuser:~] 1 $ docker login
Login with your Docker ID to push and pull images from Docker Hub. If you don't have a Docker ID, head over to https://hub.docker.com to create one.
Username: mydockerhubuser
Password: 
WARNING! Your password will be stored unencrypted in /home/myuser/.docker/config.json.
Configure a credential helper to remove this warning. See
https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/login/#credentials-store

Login Succeeded
[myuser:~] $ docker pull sath89/oracle-xe-11g:11.2
Error response from daemon: pull access denied for sath89/oracle-xe-11g, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login'
[myuser:~] 1 $
```

What is the secret nowadays for pulling images from Docker hub? It used to be so easy. Too easy clearly.

Comment: Are you sure this repository is available? Products from Oracle are normally subject to license agreements. At least you need to agree to the terms.

Comment: It can be private repo, so owner must allow access for your `mydockerhubuser` explicitly.

Comment: i'm running into the same issue, however it is my own private repo on dockerhub. Is there an additional step I need to do other than login with my docker credentials?